# Number of 6-digit positive integers with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many six-digit positive integers are there in which the first and last digits are the same?

Attempt: I know the number of 6-digit integers to be $9*10^5$. The first spot can only be numbers from {1,2,..,9} which limits the numbers for the last spot to be from the same set {1,2..,9}. Would the solution then be: $9^2*10^4 $?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial :-)

Comment: Explain why you squared the $9$.  Listen to your explanation.

Comment: Hint: it's the same as the number of $5$-digit integers.

Comment: It helps to reduce this to a smaller problem that you should be able to count immediately by hand.  So, try counting how many $2$-digit positive integers there are whose first and last digits are the same.  You should be able to quickly see they are the numbers $11,22,33,44,\dots,99$ and there are $9$ of them.  Not $81$ of them.

Answer (score 3):

There are $9$ possibilities for the first digit, $10$ possibilities for the second digit, $10$ possibilities for the third digit, $10$ possibilities for the fourth digit, $10$ possibilities for the fifth digit, and $1$ possibility for the sixth digit (once the first digit is determined, so is the last).  Multiply those numbers to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a combinatorics and you say "We have $k$ chooses for the first thingy, and then for the second thingy we...." It is assumed you are counting you options *after* you have fixed the first thingy.

There are $9$ choices for the first digit.  And there are $9$ choices for the last digit.  But it should be *very* clear they are *NOT* independent!  Whatever the choice of the first digit is, the last digit must be exactly the same.

So although there are $9$ choices for the first digit *once that digit has been determined* there is only *ONE* choice for the last digit; it must be what you chose for the first.

So the answer is $9*10^4*1= 9*10^4$.

Alternatively you could simply say "we have $5$ choices to make.  The first and last digit can be from $9$ options.  And the remaing $4$ are from $10$ options."  So the answer is $9*10^4$.

Answer (score 0):

The first digit has 9 choices.(1-9)
Each of the middle digit has 10 choices(0-9)
**The last digit has no choices(it has to be the same as the first digit.)**
So there are total 9*10^4 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding 0 from the first digit, you have 9 possibilities for the first digit and thus only 1 for the last. The rest are free for any number.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  9 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 1 \\
  \hline
\end{array}
The answer is $1*9*10^4$.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the first and last digit. That's $\binom{9}{1}$. The remaining 4 can be any of the 10 digits. That gives $10^4$. Multiplying the two you get: $\binom{9}{1}10^4$.

You can read this as "for any identical first and last digit I have $10^4$ ways to construct the number.